# How to split a string based the Comma operator in the VB.net

Tags: arrays, string, vb.net

In the below code How to split the string based on **Comma operator**

```
Dim  value as string="2.1,000123,"Garden Isle, Inc.",PKF,0.00,Faster"
Dim data() as String =value.Split(","c)
```

My current code is

```
Using sr As StreamReader = File.OpenText(path)
                Dim iBatchsize As Integer = 0
                line = sr.ReadLine()
                Do While line IsNot Nothing

                    Dim data() As String = line.Split(","c)
```

If i use , as split i could't the desired result, Can someone help us to get the below result its VB.net

```
data(0)=2.1
data(1)=000123
data(2)=Garden Isle, Inc.
data(3)=PKF
data(4)=0.00
data(5)=Faster
```

Comment: That code wouldn't even compile. If the first line actually created an actual `String` then the second line would work exactly as you want.

Comment: ie you need to escape your nested quotes

Comment: Also you can't use split if, as in your example, your data might contain comma's as part of the fields, you'll need a more sophisticated parsing mechanism to track the start/end of quoted strings

Comment: The above string were obtained while reading a csv file.

Comment: yes, that is a problem  here without using , how could i get the value

Comment: "The above string were obtained while reading a csv file". No it wasn't. That's not a valid `String`. Are you actually trying to parse a CSV file?  If so, you should use a `TextFieldParser`, which will handle quoted values that contain delimiters automatically.

Comment: this is my current code Using sr As StreamReader = File.OpenText(path)
                Dim iBatchsize As Integer = 0
                line = sr.ReadLine()
                Do While line IsNot Nothing
                    Dim data() As String = line.Split(","c)

Comment: As jmcilhinney says, if you're parsing from a CSV file there are dedicated classes already available to read the data into variables for you. Look up the class suggested, and/or do some more research into it

Comment: As I said, use a `TextFieldParser`.  You can either just pass the file name to the constructor or you can create the `StreamReader` first and pass that.  I recommend the former, unless you specifically need the `StreamReader` for something else.  The documentation for the [`TextFieldParser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx) class includes code examples.